# How to implement instagram lux effect using GPUImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, instagram, gpuimage

I mean, which filters (brightness, contrast, exposure, gamma, saturation, etc...) and which values do I need to use to achieve similar photo effect?

Comment: I don't think there's any single filter that will achieve this. Instagram's Lux effect appears to be a more complex image enhancement, which adapts based on the content of the image. If I had to guess, I'd say they were using some sort of histogram equalization. GPUImage can extract a histogram, but it's up to you to analyze that and convert it to a color mapping table for a later lookup filter to be applied to a given image. There may also be some sharpening and color saturation enhancement here.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel:) Try [FIlterKit](http://www.getfilterkit.com/) (based on GPUImage)

Comment: I'm working with GPUImage in my app, so I don't want to add one more similar framework to my app.

Comment: Can I add it to my project and it will use already added GPUImage?

Comment: Yes, you can: https://github.com/eklipse2k8/FilterKit/tree/master/lib - GPUImage is added as submodule to FilterKit

Comment: @nik Could you give me some details about how to implement LUX effect?